# Kafka behind Traefik on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, load-balancing, traefik

I am trying to configure a Kafka cluster behind Traefik but my producers and client (that are outside kubernetes) don't connect to the bootstrap-servers. They keep saying:

> "no resolvable boostrap servers in the given url"

Actually here is the Traefik ingress:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
    "kind": "Ingress",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nppl-ingress",
        "annotations": {
            "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "traefik",
            "traefik.frontend.rule.type": "PathPrefixStrip"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "host": "" ,
                "http": {
                    "paths": [
                        {
                            "path": "/zuul-gateway",
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "zuul-gateway",
                                "servicePort": "zuul-port"
                            }
                        },                      
                        {
                            "path": "/kafka",
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "kafka-broker",
                                "servicePort": "kafka-port"
                            }

[..]
    }
```

What I give to the kafka consumers/producers is the public IP of Traefik.
Here is the flow: [Kafka producers/consumers] -> Traefik(exposed as Load Balancer) -> [Kafka-Cluster]

Is there any solution? Otherwise I was thinking to add a kafka-rest proxy (https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) between Traefik and the kafka brokers but I think isn't the ideal solution.

Comment: I am neither familiar with Kafka nor traefik, but I think you miss the load balancer. You use traefik as an ingress object which maps your services to the API http requests, but you need to also define a LB that forwards the traffic of to your ingress. This is usual with KVM or bare metal k8s clusters. Otherwise my next guess is that the servicePort should be numerical rather than string.

Comment: Isn' the same of what I did? I exposed Traefik as a load balancer, so it is like and entry point for the cluster.

Comment: I believe you are exposing an http protocol endpoint but kafka is not using http, this may be why this is failing.

Answer (score 2):

I did. You can refer to it, in kubernetes ,deployment kafka.yaml

```
   env:
    - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
      value: "1"
    - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
      value: "test:1:1"
    - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
      value: "zookeeper:2181"
    - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
      value: "INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka-com:30322"
    - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
      value: "INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:30322"
    - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
      value: "INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT"
    - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
      value: "INSIDE"
```

kafka service,the external service invocation address, or traefik proxy address

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-com
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    k8s-app: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kafka
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: innerport
    targetPort: 9092
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 30322
    name: outport 
    targetPort: 30322
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30322
  type: NodePort
```

Ensure that Kafka external port and nodePort port are consistent,Other services call kafka-com:30322, my blog write this [config_kafka_in_kubernetes](https://bbotte.github.io/virtualization/config_kafka_in_kubernetes), hope to help U !

Comment: 1) Strimzi Operator does this for you 2) How does this answer about Traefik?